# Return multiple fields as a single field value in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

Hai all,
    I want to combine two columns in table and return as single column.

Eg: If the table having fields A,B should return in single column as C with both fields values.

Please Help

**EDIT**

table fields....

```
               A    B
               1    3
               2    4
```

reslut will be

```
                C
                1
                2
                3
                4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit per OP's updated post:**

```
SELECT A AS C
UNION ALL
SELECT B AS C
```

Comment: table fields are integer type.and the two fields having different values.So the return column have all values in both fields.

Answer (score 3):

This works:

```
SELECT A as C FROM t
union all
select B as C from t
```